# Calculate the amount of days between two dates in ms word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have a Word document with two mergefields, each containing a date

`{ MERGEFIELD myObj.startDate \* MERGEFORMAT }`--> outputs `01.01.2014`

`{ MERGEFIELD myObj.endDate \* MERGEFORMAT }` --> outputs `31.01.2014`

Now I would like to calculate how many days there are between those two dates, so I have to "substract" startDate from endDate, e.g. `31.01.2014 - 01.01.2014` --> 31

Unfortunately this doesn't work:
`{ { MERGEFIELD myObj.endDate \* MERGEFORMAT } - { MERGEFIELD myObj.startDate \* MERGEFORMAT } }`

Does anyone know if it's even possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Date differences are also discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353619/word-create-formula-to-subtract-dates-in-word/20361233#20361233

Answer (score 2):

The solution below was taken from a document posted to the Windows Secrets forum by Paul Edstein. It contains a trove of information on how to perform date calculations in Word field codes and can be found in this thread:

[Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154368-Microsoft-Word-Date-Calculation-Tutorial)

Because Word field codes do not copy and paste easily, I have inserted a screen cap of the code below. I suggest that you become a member of the free Windows Secrets forum so you can download this document and copy the field codes from Mr. Edstein's original document into your own document as this will be easier than keyboarding the text and creating the field code brackets manually (CTRL-F9 in Word).

The following code should work with your date format of DD.MM.YYYY. If you bookmark your `myObj.startDate` and `myObj.endDate` field codes within your document using the `StartDate` and `EndDate` bookmark names, the code below will work as is. Because the SET command is designed to work with bookmarks, this solution will probably not work if you replace the `EndDate` and `StartDate` bookmarks from this example with your `MERGEFIELD` field codes. However, I have not experimented with this, so I do not know if the object model has this flexibility.

[image]

Comment: Update: The tutorial can also be found at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html and http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party. It is a valuable resource. Anyone trying to do date calculations in Word should keep a copy on their computer.