# In Word is there a formula for getting the difference between two mergefield dates?

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have two merge fields in Word that I am needing to do a calculation for another field which needs to contain the difference between these two dates. Is there a way to have that calculated upon merge?

Comment: To see how to do this and just about everything else you might want to do with dates in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party. In particular, look at the items titled *Calculate the # Days Difference Between Two Dates* and *Calculate the # Years Months & Days Difference Between Two Dates*. Do read the document's introductory material.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the amount of days between two dates in ms word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887399/calculate-the-amount-of-days-between-two-dates-in-ms-word)

Comment: I strongly recommend the resource linked by macropod. It is a bit of a tough read but you do not need to read all of it. Read the introductory material and then skip to the field you need. You can copy the field from the tutorial and paste in your document. This tutorial is something you should keep as a resource. The second link will take you to the same place. --- The thing is, Word is designed to handle simple calculations, and calendar calculations are really not simple, thanks in part to the vanity of certain Roman Emperors.